# JavaScript regex to parse: set Properly Name Is X = value # comment

Tags: javascript, regex

i would like to have 5 groups for parsing a single line like

```
set Property name is long = value could be anything 1.0 # comment
 1             2          3         4                      5
```

Infront of `set` there could be whitespace. There is always `=` between the property name and value. A string could end with comments, starting with `#`. So far I tried

```
\b(set)\b\s*(.*)\b(=)\b(.*)\n
```

but quickly realised that this task is beyond my limited knowledge of regex.

p.s. This has to be in JavaScript regex (no lookahead, AFIK).

Comment: Javascript RegExp flavor has positive and negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly here's a regex that should fit your need:

```
var rgx = /^\s*(set) ?(.+?)(?:\s+?(=)\s+?)(.+?)(#.*)?$/gm
```

This matches:

```
set Property name is long = value could be anything 1.0 # comment

set foobar baz bazinga = nhaca
```

You can test this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/mM3dP2/2)

EDIT: Fixed to include # char in "comment" group

Comment: could you please modify it to have `#` as a part of the last group?

Comment: i also don't need `g` and `m`  (I am parsing in Atom editor plugin)

Comment: `^\s*(set) ?(.+?)(?:\s+?(=)\s+?)(.+?)(#.*)?\n` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If this is javascript, then you can use this: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gF2oK8/1)

```
(?:\s*)(set)(.*)(=)([^#]*)(\#.*)*
```

which means:

```
(?:\s*) - leading spaces, not captured
(set)   - set
(.*)    - property name
(=)     - equals sign
([^#]*) - value which doesn't include a comment sign
(\#.*)* - optional comment
```

Comment: This matches something like this:
set blagh

Comment: this fails when there is no `#`, e.g.: set Property name is long = value could be anything 1.0
set alsdflkj = asdflnk